# Position DIV absolute and get "Top" position based on other DIV

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to position a div below another div which has a varying height using position absolute and jQuery:
EG:

div1 has a dynamic height (not set), div2 needs to sit below it.

**The jQuery needed:**

Get height of div1 and add css to div2 "top: 'div1height'px".

**Result**

That way div2 always sits below div1 and never overlaps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So why don't you try it ??? .... where is your code?

Comment: I havnt tried it because I dont know how to get the height of div1 using jquery and add that as css to div2. There is no code as I havnt written any for it.

Comment: Then this question doesn't fit SO just with a little search with google you can find that ... or searching on the API of Jquery ... **Search:** Get height of elemtn on Jquery ... Set top to element css on Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HTML
<div id="d_1">
</div>

<div id="d_2">
</div>

JQUERY

var d1_height = $("#d_1").height();
d1_height = d1_height + "px";
$("#d_2").css("top", d1_height);
```

You can find more about JQUERY css proprety: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp and here
http://api.jquery.com/css/
And you should read more about JQUERY here: http://api.jquery.com